# Abandon Checkout Tackling the problem

Tags: usability-testing, e-commerce, checkout, recommendations

A little bit of context my boss has asked to look into why abandon cart rate is so high.I’m not a Ux designer so I’m a little overwhelmed with where to start. What is the best way to tackle this problem. I was also thinking of using user zoom or remote testing solution to get qualitative data. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is it high compared to industry standard or just compared to your boss's expectations?

Comment: Yea what @LukeSawczak said, cart abandon rates (bounce rates) are usually quite high.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that contribute to cart abandonment, off the top of my head:

1. Unexpected additional costs during checkout.
2. Forcing user to create an account, no guest checkout option.
3. Complicated checkout process.

Those are just some reasons, I found some more resources that might help you out:

https://www.cartstack.com/blog/9-reasons-high-cart-abandonment-rate/

https://databox.com/high-shopping-cart-abandonment-rate-causes

This link talks about average cart abandonment rate:

https://baymard.com/lists/cart-abandonment-rate